# Increase Volume by 1 in applescript

Tags: applescript, volume

I'm trying to replicate the function of the volume keys, but in applescript. I can't get it to work though. The increase volume button puts the volume at max and the decrease volume button does the same. Anyone know what i'm doing wrong? Heres my code:

```
-- increase volume

on increaseVolumeHandler_(sender)
    tell application "finder"
    set theOutput to output volume of (get volume settings)
    set volume output volume (theOutput + 6.25)
    end tell
    do shell script "afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Pop.aiff"
end increaseVolumeHandler_

-- decrease volume

on decreaseVolumeHandler_(sender)
    tell application "finder"
    set theOutput to output volume of (get volume settings)
    set volume output volume (theOutput - 6.25)
    end tell
    do shell script "afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Pop.aiff"
end decreaseVolumeHandler_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those functions work for me on 10.7.5, what OSX version are you trying on?

Also you could remove the redundant code of the sender argument and the tell finder block, e.g,

```
on increaseVolumeHandler_()
    set theOutput to output volume of (get volume settings)
    set volume output volume (theOutput + 6.25)
    do shell script "afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Pop.aiff"
end increaseVolumeHandler_
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason it was the tell block causing the issue.